# Android: Overriding onCreate method of main activity

Tags: java, android

I have a Java activity like so.

```
package com.xxx.yyy.overrideoncreate;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("DEBUG","Original oncreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I wish to split some of the onCreate instructions to a separate class, so I created this too.

```
package com.xxx.yyy.overrideoncreate;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by oox on 26/6/17.
 */

public class SubClass extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("DEBUG","Overridden");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

I intend for subClass.onCreate to override MainActivity.onCreate -- both Overridden and original oncreate messages should be displayed. However, that did not seem to happen, the overridden message did not appear in the Logcat.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set your `SubClass` as the start activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: show, how you start the `SubClass` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `SubClass`'s `onCreate` to be called, an instance of `SubClass` should be created instead of an instance of `MainActivity` when the application is launched.

For that to happen, `SubClass` should become the actual main activity of your application (i.e. the activity class registered in the AndroidManifest.xml which gets launched when the application is launched).

Comment: Ah. That helped. Thanks very much.